# hook_boot and Varnish

Tags: 6, caching, cookies, proxies

I have a module that implements a hook_boot(), and it checks if user is going to access home page and if user does not have a specific cookie. If both verifications are true, it redirects user to a /welcome page and set cookie. So the second time a user tries to access home page, it will see that user has the cookie and will not redirect.

Recently, I installed Varnish on my site, and everytime I try to access home page, I get to /welcome page. It never skips.

I'm not sure but it looks like the first time I access home page, when I still don't have cookie, it caches the home page, shows /welcome page and set cookie. Then, second time I try to access home, it gets the cached page (which thinks I don't have cookie) and redirect again to /welcome page, even though I have cookie.

I tried not caching home page but it didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Varnish - you must consider that for anonymous users PHP code will not execute at all - they will retrieve only static HTML.

In you case solution can be as following:

1. On welcome page set cookie by JavaScript not PHP.
2. Using Varnish vcl script check if user loads homepage and has cookie. If not - then redirect it to welcome page.

Now item #2 is made in PHP code but you need rewrite it using Varnish.
You can also write item #2 using JavaScript but it will work much slower and user will see browser redirection.